# Modebar disappears when adding manual Plotly events (e.g. onLegendClick) - plotly.js/react-plotly.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, plotly, plotly.js

I've encountered an issue where the modebar disappears completely when I added a Plotly event to interact with the chart and manually remove a trace when toggling a legend.

Is there another event that needs to be trigger before/after I run Plot.deleteTrace?  I've also tried Plotly.restyle and Plotly.react with the same results.

```
import React, { useRef } from 'react';
import Plot from 'react-plotly.js';
import Plotly from 'plotly.js';

const DataChart = (props) => {
  const { data, layout, scrollZoom } = props;

  const dataChartNode = useRef();

  const handleOnLegendClick = (eventdata) => {

    {/* Custom code when interacting with the legend labels */}

    Plotly.deleteTraces(dataChartNode.current.el, eventdata.curveNumber);
    // Plotly.react(dataChartNode.current.el, {visible: false}, [eventdata.curveNumber]);
    // Plotly.restyle(dataChartNode.current.el, {visible: false}, [eventdata.curveNumber]);
  }

  return (
    <Plot
      ref={dataChartNode}
      data={data}
      layout={{
        ...layout,
        dragmode: 'pan'
      }}
      config={{
        displaylogo: false,
        modeBarButtonsToRemove: [
          'select2d', 'lasso2d', 'autoScale2d', // 2D options
          'toggleSpikelines'
        ],
        responsive: true,
        // scrollZoom,
        showTips: false
      }}
      onLegendClick={handleOnLegendClick}
    />
  )
}

export default DataChart;
```

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-easley-97jrn

Comment: Could you make it an online demo? Which may help others to understand your problem very quick!

Comment: Hey @keikai (and others) sorry for the delay.

Here's the demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-easley-97jrn

The modebar appears when you hover over the chart, but once you toggle the charts via the legend, the modebar is removed completely.  I tried to force it open in the "config" object -- displayModeBar: true -- but that doesn't help either.